# A group homomorphism satisfying square property for certain elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

The homomorphism $\psi$ takes $G$ to $G$, where $G$ is a group, and let $b=|G|$ (*i.e.*, the number of elements in $G$). Let $a$ be the number of elements $e$ in $G$ such that $\psi(e)=e^2$. Find when $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{3}{100}$? I also was interested in the largest possible value of $\frac{a}{b}$ besides $1$?

I tried simulating this on my own for very small groups but couldn't get anywhere. The second question is out of curiosity, I'm not sure it is possible to find out.

Comment: Are you trying to find all possible $G$ and $\psi$ for which $a/b=3/100$?

Comment: I am trying to characterize the possible $G$ and $\psi$, yes. And I realized that $a/b$ is just the fraction of elements, as said by @magnets17.